# Calculating sum of price

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of products and i want to Calculate the total price of all products but i don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

```
 CountTotal: function() {
            var total;
            var totalsum;
            this.state.data.forEach(function(item, index) {
              total += item.price + item.quantity;
              totalsum += total + index.length;
            });
              console.log(totalsum);
          },
```

Comment: Take a look at `reduce` array method.

Comment: `index.length` this will  return `undefined`. index is the iteration count and integers do not have `length` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 CountTotal: function() {
            var total;
            this.state.data.forEach(function(item, index) {
              total += item.price * item.quantity;
            });
            console.log(total);
          },
```

Or with `Array#reduce`

```
 CountTotal: function() {
            var total = this.state.data.reduce(function(res,item) {
              return res + (item.price * item.quantity);
            }, 0);
            console.log(total);
          },
```

Comment: If you are using `reduce`, you need to **return** a value from the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: `return res + (item.price * item.quantity)` makes more sense, there's no need to mutate a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleQuantityChange = id => {
    const carsSelected = this.state.selectedProducts;
    var totalPrice= this.state.selectedProducts.reduce(function(res,item) {
              return res + item.price;
            }, 0);
    const oldTotal = this.state.totalPrice
    const newPrice = id.price + oldTotal
    this.setState({
      selectedProducts: [...carsSelected, id],
      totalPrice: totalPrice
    });
  }
```

//reduce function can sum price of products.